# editing crontab returns code 1076

Tags: cron

I am trying to edit crontab using the following:

```
crontab -e
```

However, this returns the code 1076 and does not allow me to edit an existing crontab.  I can list the crontab out via crontab -l.  I believe I have access permissions to edit the crontab.  Any idea on how t troubleshoot this?

Comment: needed to set the vi editor - works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you have permission by using the following sequence of command, generally on CentOS standard user do not have permission neither to list / read the crontab file and they need to perform a su to impersonificate root or to be defined as administrator.

```
crontab -l
ls -lrt /var/spool/cron/$user
su
crontab -l
ls -lrt /var/spool/cron/root
```